# Is wasm safe to store client side secrets?

Tags: security, electron, webassembly

The security context of my question is as follows:

I currently have an [electron](https://electronjs.org/) desktop application which runs my webapp. Inside my app there is a feature which allows a authenticated user to access a document(pdf) which is password protected. The document is prepared on server and password is generated using SHA256 hash of 10 character string. The 10 characters are made up of two parts 1) variable doc id and 2nd fixed salt.

On the client inside electron currently i have a native node module which was written in C and compiled using node-gyp. I make a call to this module which contains the code to generate the same password using the two parts of the password. The whole purpose of having this native node module on the client was that as the module is a compiled binary it can not be reverse engineered and no one can access my secret salt. If salt is discovered then the other part is easy to find and hence all docs are accessible to attacker.

I read about WebAssembly and how it compiles lower language code to wasm which can then be loaded in to browsers. This effectively means i can use the same C code that i use in my native module but now over the web instead of in electron.

My doubts were on the security and reverse engineering part of wasm module that gets produced. I read that it is possible to reverse engineer and get back the C file from wasm but the format which it gives is not exactly the same as source and how much can it help the attacker is again a question.

Some threads that i have read

- https://twitter.com/jebdec/status/1012749064696295425?lang=en
- https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=17507767
- https://www.reddit.com/r/WebAssembly/comments/8qmxjv/can_we_decompile_wasm_to_ccsource/

Apart from security concerns i think i maybe using wasm for a wrong purpose here as being on the open web if there is code the source of which is not viewable and auditable, it presents a very large security issue on the whole.

Any comments/advice will be helpful.

Comment: `as the module is a compiled binary it can not be reverse engineered and no one can access my secret salt` - are you sure about that?

Comment: pretty much well explained in below answer and above comment. 1. native binary is not _secure_, it can be also reverse engineered. 2. it does not matter of what target of binary you are aiming (native, wasm, or even js) it doesn't guarantee security.

Comment: @rkosegi no my assumption is wrong as stated in the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First to answer your question. No, WASM is not safe to store client secrets for the scenario that you are describing.

And your current implementation doesn't seem to be secure as well (from the limited info available).

If you are compiling your code to binary just so that an attacker cannot find your **fixed salt** I got bad news for you. It is very much possible to extract data from a binary file.

Just think of a case where you have your salt stored as a variable inside a c program.

```
int main() {
 char* mySaltVar = "my salt";
 char* b = "my other string";
}
```

and you compile this with gcc and create binary. you might think these strings cannot be read as they inside the binary but you can just run `strings` program on the binary to get the strings inside the binary.

```
sk$ strings binary.out 
my salt
my other string
```

The two strings are extracted from the binary.

This is an over simplified example to show that everything in your code is inside the binary. In most of the cases the compiler throws away some info to make the binary as efficient as possible. In such cases attacker would use reverse engineering tools to figure out what is going on inside the binary.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the info. I didn't know that. So is there any option to hide my salt in native binary such that it is at least very hard to reverse engineer (such that it is not worth the effort ?)

Comment: Inside code, you can calculate the salt from a function, e,g. some string concatenation, and std::to_string(num) operations. This is much more difficult to extract.